Best practice when working with Green Screen (Video Editing)
I'm working with some footage that was filmed in front of a green screen. I'd like to remove the green screen, split some of the clips, adjust the background etc and then export the resulting video.
I'm not sure about the most efficient approach of doing it. Right now I've created one scene for video editing and one scene for each of the video clips that have a green screen. In the scenes for the video clips I used the compositor with the 'Movie Clip', 'Keying' and 'Compositing' nodes. This works well, all green parts of the clips have been removed. Then, in the video editing scene, in Video Editing - Sequencer, I added one strip for each scene (Add - Scene). Everything is imported fine and looks as it should but it's impossible to do any editing (splitting clips, ...) because playback is incredibly slow (even though I've got a very fast computer). I assume that blender is computing the keying mask during playback, which makes it so slow (is that really the issue?).
Is there a way of pre-computing ('baking') the strips of the scenes so that the computation doesn't have to be done during playback, while I'm doing my editing? Or maybe there is a better way of achieving what I'm trying to do? (I didn't want to export the alpha masks of the individual scenes in advance because for some reason that I can't explain I've assumed that the result wouldn't be as good that way. Is that right?)
Thanks for your help!

usually the workflow would be: replace the green screen with the background you want in the compositor then export as an image sequence. Once you've done that for every shot, import all the image sequences in the video editor and edit them to make your scene
